# Filter for List View Where 'Related To" is blank or Related to 'Intake'

Tags: filters, lookup-filter

I would like a Tasks View, in which the 'Relate To' field is either blank or the object that 'Relate To' is connected to is an 'Intake'.  Is this possible?  I think the problem is that 'Intake' isn't even a valid choice there.

I've tried:

```
(Related To equals "") OR (Related To equals 'Intake')
(Related To equals "") OR (Related To equals 'Intake)
(Related To equals "" OR Related To equals 'Intake')
(Related To equals "" OR Related To equals Intake)
(Related To is blank OR Related To = 'Intake')
```

Comment: Is this on Nonprofit Cloud? Can you share in your question, why you want to do this when you think that Intake is an impossible choice?

Comment: Yes, it's for a Nonprofit. One colleague needs to see a list of all phone calls that are not related to a case.  This list has been historically created with a list using a filter 'Related to' equals [nothing chosen].  However, if a colleague makes a phone call from within an intake, 'Related to' equals 'Intake'.